# Uncaught TypeError:Class constructor Scene cannot be invoked without 'new' line:391 of:file:///storage/emulated/0/threejs/libs/physi.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, physijs, ammo.js

I have been using Physijs with the older version of three.js and it works perfectly
But when I downloaded the latest version of threejs it doesn't work even to just put a plane mesh on the scene

It brings out this error
 `Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor Scene cannot be invoked without 'new' line:391 of:file:///storage /emulated/0/threejs /learning-threejs/libs/physi .js`

I don't understand why exactly
Here's my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example 01.01 - Basic skeleton</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/three.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/dat.gui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/TrackballControls.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/physi.js"></script>    

<style>
        body {
            /* set margin to 0 and overflow to hidden, to
             use the complete page */
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Div which will hold the Output -->
<div id="WebGL-output">
</div>
<!-- Javascript code that runs our Three.js examples -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    // once everything is loaded, we run our Three.js stuff.
    function init() {
    Physijs.scripts.worker = '../libs/physijs_worker.js';
    Physijs.scripts.ammo = '../libs/ammo.js';
    //renderer
    var renderer=new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true})
    renderer.setSize(innerWidth,innerHeight)
    renderer.setPixelRatio=devicePixelRatio
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled=true
    renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0xff00ff))
    //physijs scene
    var scene=new Physijs.Scene
    scene.setGravity(new THREE.Vector3(0,-300,-50))

//ground
var groundgeo=new THREE.PlaneGeometry(50,50)
var groundmat=new Physijs.createMaterial(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xd2b48c ,side:THREE.DoubleSide}))
var ground=new Physijs.PlaneMesh(groundgeo,groundmat,0)
ground.rotation.x=-0.5*Math.PI
ground.position.set(-20.0,0,0.0)
ground.receiveShadow=true 
scene.add(ground)
var camera=new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40,innerWidth/innerHeight,0.1,10000)
 camera.position.set(70,65,0)
 camera.lookAt(ground.position)
 scene.add(camera)
var trackballControls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);
 trackballControls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
 trackballControls.zoomSpeed = 1.0;
 trackballControls.panSpeed = 1.0;
 trackballControls.staticMoving = true;
document.getElementById("WebGL-output").appendChild(renderer.domElement)
render()
var step=0
function render(){
scene.simulate(undefined,2)
trackballControls.update()
requestAnimationFrame(render)
renderer.render(scene,camera)
}}
    window.onload = init()
</script>   
</body>
```

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: This sounds like an error that would occur when mixing a new version of three.js with code written for an older version.  The code throwing the error (e.g. `new Scene()`) is not part of the code snippet above and might be in one of the imported scripts. Most likely Physijs requires an older version of three.js

Comment: It looks like Physijs [last update was in 2015](https://github.com/chandlerprall/Physijs/commit/7a5372647f5af47732e977c153c0d1c2550950a0) and it was compatible with threejs v73. Threejs today is at v135.

Comment: So is there any solution to this

Answer (score 0):

The new version of three js doesn't support physi.js but it support Cannon.js
So cannon.js(or other recent physics library) should be used instead of physi.js